# Caliburn.Micro Bootstrapper 'BuildUp' method throws exception when Simple Injector is used

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

I had no problems with the built-in CM SimpleContainer, but today I needed to go to [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org).

When I call an asynchronous method through `cal:Message.Attach` the Bootstrapper's `BuildUp` method raises an exception:

> An exception of type `'SimpleInjector.ActivationException'` occurred in
>   SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The constructor of type SequentialResult
>   contains the parameter with name 'enumerator' and type
>   `IEnumerator<IResult>` that is not registered. Please ensure
>   `IEnumerator<IResult>` is registered, or change the constructor of
>   SequentialResult.

Here's my bootstrapper class:

```
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.RegisterSingleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.RegisterSingleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();

        _container.Verify();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var instance = _container.GetInstance(service);

        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        IServiceProvider provider = _container;
        Type collectionType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(service);
        var services = (IEnumerable<object>)provider.GetService(collectionType);
        return services ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        var registration = _container.GetRegistration(instance.GetType(), true);
        registration.Registration.InitializeInstance(instance);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        return new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() };
    }
```

Part of XAML:

```
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Padding="10" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="#DFDFDF" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button IsCancel="True" Content="{Resx Key=Close}" />
            <Button IsDefault="True" MinWidth="{Resx Key=CheckOrUpdateBtnWidth, DefaultValue='115'}" Margin="8,0,0,0"
                    cal:Message.Attach="CheckUpdateAsync" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Part of VM:

```
    public async Task CheckUpdateAsync()
    {
        IsUpdateDownloading = true;

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                var http = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage rm = await http.GetAsync(UpdateInfo.DownloadUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, Cts.Token);

                long size = rm.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault();

                var downloader = FileDownloader.Create(UpdateInfo.DownloadUri);

                byte[] data = downloader.Download(Cts.Token);
                downloader.ValidateHash(data, CloudManager.UpdateInfo.Sha256);
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsUpdateDownloading = false;
            ProgressValue = 0;
        }
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you show the relevant xaml and the code that should be called when 'message attached' is invoked?

Comment: @Ric.Net I've updated the question.

Comment: I think its hitting the CTOR of SequentialResult, which is `public SequentialResult(IEnumerator<IResult> enumerator) { 
             this.enumerator = enumerator; 
}` when it sees the `IEnumerator<IResult>` it doesn't know how to resolve the interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate where and why a SequentialResult is created? I'm missing the bigger picture here. The problem is clear, SquentialResult isn't registered. This is why .Verify() can't show you at startup that you're missing a registration for the ctor parameter IEnumerator<IResult>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Message.Attach()` will internally in C.M. use [CoRoutines](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines). Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/Coroutine.cs) of C.M. I see this code:

```
 public static Func<IEnumerator<IResult>, IResult> CreateParentEnumerator = 
     inner => new SequentialResult(inner);
```

i.e. if not overwritten the default `SequentialResult<IResult>` is used.

Furtheron:

```
 var enumerator = CreateParentEnumerator(coroutine);
 IoC.BuildUp(enumerator);
```

This is were the exception comes from. `BuildUp` is called internally and as you are calling directly into the container to find the registration Simple Injector will throw an `ActivationException`.

In most cases you won't need to implement the `BuildUp` method at all. I can't think of any reason why you would want to use this method when you use Simple Injector as your DI container. I normally don't implement this method.

BuildUp is a method which you would typically need if you need to inject (using property injection) into components that can't be created using the normal Simple Injector pipeline. You can read about the details in the Simple Injector documentation [here](https://simpleinjector.org/extensibility+building-up-external-instances).

In this case I think however that you don't need to Build Up the `SequentialResult` in this case. There is nothing you need to inject in this C.M. default class.

So the question here is are there any classes you need to `BuildUp`? Your application design should normally only use classes defined in the application itself which you register in Simple Injector and which can be resolved directly using `GetInstance()`.

If the answer is 'no', you never inject dependencies in external classes, remove the BuildUp() method completely.

If you however need to BuildUp() other classes, this will only make sense if you override the default [`PropertyInjectionBehaviour`](https://simpleinjector.org/extensibility.html#overriding-property-injection-behavior). If you don't override this, making a call to `registration.InitializeInstance` doesn't make sense at all, because Simple Injector doesn't know what to inject, because Simple Injector only supports [Explicit Property Injection](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=property%20injection#property-injection) out of the box. You can create some sort of implicit behavior when overriding the default `PropertyInjectionBehaviour`.

To summarize, I think you should just remove the BuildUp method completely as the current implementation doesn't do anything. InitializeInstance will inject nothing.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I don't need the BuildUp method. Thanks for the detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this was an example from Simple Injector.
var repositoryAssembly = typeof(SqlUserRepository).Assembly;   

var registrations =
from type in repositoryAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
where type.Namespace == "MyComp.MyProd.BL.SqlRepositories"
where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
select new { Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), Implementation = type };

foreach (var reg in registrations) {
    container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient);
}
```

While I know that CM with SelectedAssemblies override in place is "suppose" to be the catch all for all things Assembly related, I speculate the couple of lines in GetAllInstances is not getting everything that is necessary for CM.  I think you need to expand to include `type.GetIntefaces().Any()`.  Which I hope would be enough to grab the SequentialResult's CTOR needs.

I haven't ever used Simple Injector, but I say it would work very similar and might have alittle bit better handle for open generics.  I think there is something missing where you should be doing alittle more registration in Configure.  I am assuming up to that point nothing else dies or fails prior to that section of XAML that "throws" the Injector issue..  This doesn't appear to be a CM problem but a Simple Injector configuration.